# How to prevent Make from randomly overriding files?

Tags: make, gnu-make

Suppose I am in an empty directory. If I now create a Makefile containing nothing but `all: randomFilename` and an empty file called `randomFilename.sh`, then GNU Make will perform `cat randomFilename.sh >randomFilename; chmod a+x randomFilename` when `make` is called.

```
$ echo 'all: randomFilename' > Makefile
$ make
make: *** No rule to make target 'randomFilename', needed by 'all'.  Stop.
$ touch randomFilename.sh
$ make
cat randomFilename.sh >randomFilename 
chmod a+x randomFilename
$ make -v | head -n2
GNU Make 4.0
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

Worse yet, Make overrides a file called `randomFilename`, if it already exists.

```
$ echo "My content" > randomFilename
$ echo "My content, all gone" > randomFilename.sh
$ make -B
cat randomFilename.sh >randomFilename 
chmod a+x randomFilename
$ cat randomFilename
My content, all gone
```

I would like to find the reason why Make does this and a way to prevent the behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is the result of the built-in suffix rules of Make (in this case for legacy versions of the Source Code Control System [[1](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html)]). The built-in suffix rules can be disabled by specifying an empty `.SUFFIXES` pseudo-target [[2](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Suffix-Rules.html)]:

```
$ echo '.SUFFIXES:'          >  Makefile
$ echo 'all: randomFilename' >> Makefile
$ make
make: *** No rule to make target 'randomFilename', needed by 'all'.  Stop.
$ touch randomFilename.sh
$ make
make: *** No rule to make target 'randomFilename', needed by 'all'.  Stop.
```

Comment: Could you explain? I cannot see any filename that would trigger a SCCS rule.

Comment: [Quoting:](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html) "For the benefit of SCCS, a file n is copied from n.sh and made executable (by everyone)."

Comment: Ah, OK - now I understand. So this is not compatibility to SCCS but rather compatibility to ancient versions of SCCS (from before ~ 1986) when SCCS did not yet retain the x-bit. This is just a copy from rules from UNIX make from 1976.

Comment: Possibly, I'm not terribly familiar with SCCS.

Comment: Well, I am the current SCCS maintainer, so I know ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you describe does not depend on the make program but on the shell.

If you have a POSIX shell and if you let every command line in the makefile start with:

`set -o noclobber;`

existing files will no longer be overwritten with the `>`operator.

Note that this still does not affect other programs that might be called and that create files.

Comment: The thing is that the executed command is not defined in the Makefile. Make just for some reason copies the randomFilename.sh file, which isn't even mentioned in the Makefile.

Comment: So find the place where the file is cerated and it is a script, add `set -o noglobber` early ehough in the script.

Comment: I suppose you mean something like `set -o noclobber; make`? That is not going to prevent Make from overriding anything, since these options do not automatically propagate to subsequently invoked shells. Consider `set -o noclobber; bash -c 'echo test > file'`. Here, the `noclobber` setting doesn't affect the manually executed `bash`. It does in `set -o noclobber; (echo test > file)`, but that's because we use the shell syntax to advertise that we're creating a sub-shell.

Comment: Even if it worked, though, I'd prefer an answer that explains why Make behaves so rather than one that explains how to work around it's eccentrities.

Comment: @Witiko your proposal will of course not work. As I mentioned before, this is a property of the shell and `make` cannot honor settings it cannot see as the setting in  question is shell local.

Comment: Then where do you propose I add the command? The directory is empty and there is only the `all: randomFilename` line in the `Makefile`. The `cat randomFilename.sh >randomFilename; chmod a+x randomFilename` commands are executed by Make for some unknown reason, so I can't prefix them with `set -o noglobber`.

Comment: The problem here is not a file being overriden, but Make executing commands that are nowhere to be found in the `Makefile`. Did you perhaps misread my original question?

Comment: You send a make output in your question that is `cat randomFilename.sh >randomFilename`. As make only prints such commands when they are defined in the makefile, I recommended you to add the set command in the same line but before the command that redirects the output to the file.

Comment: As stated in the minimal example, the `all: randomFilename` line is all that the `Makefile` contains and yet, if `randomFilename.sh` exists in the directory, Make performs `cat randomFilename.sh >randomFilename; chmod a+x randomFilename` when `make` is called. I'd like to find the reason why Make does this and a way to disable the behavior.

Comment: Most make implementations support a `-d` option for debugging.

Comment: Thanks, the debugging flag helped me find the correct answer. These legacy features of GNU Make will be the end of me one day, I swear. Once I spent the whole day trying to find out why several `Makefile`s in a project wouldn't work the way they should and then I found out that a variable they declared (`MAKEFILES`) was reserved.